# TFS/VS2015 Project Documents URL Add-On

Tags: visual-studio

I'm wondering if anyone has seen a Add-On for VS 2015 that would allow you to got into the <kbd>Project</kbd> > <kbd>Documents</kbd> section and then be able to right click on a document and view its properties?

Mainly we are interested in grabbing the document's URL. Currently we are forced to go to the project's portal and get the link from there.

If there isn't one could someone point me to a good reference on making an Add-On to try to do this?

Comment: This should be doable if there is a context menu already. This may get you started: http://www.diaryofaninja.com/blog/2014/02/18/who-said-building-visual-studio-extensions-was-hard